# Cannot deploy MySQL pod. --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, digital-ocean, persistent-volume-claims

I'm trying to setup a MySQL pod on Digital Ocean with Kubernetes.

I kept getting this error:

```
Initializing database
2019-03-05T14:32:58.707421Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-03-05T14:32:58.708753Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2019-03-05T14:32:58.711746Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

My yaml as a lot of stuff but the lines that interest this part of the config are the following.

```
# ------------------- Persistent Volume Claim ------------------- #

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-mysql-volume-claim
  ...
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: do-block-storage

---

# ------------------- Deployment ------------------- #

kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
...
spec:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.7
          ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-mysql-volume
              mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
      volumes:
        - name: test-mysql-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: test-mysql-volume-claim

---
```

If I comment out the PVC and the lines relative to PVC in the deployment config, everything works.

Also, if I change

```
mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
```

to

```
mountPath: "/data"
```

it works. But I obviously need `/var/lib/mysql`...

It happens also on brand new clusters.

Any idea?

Comment: Apparently it has been a [known issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69) since 2015!

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl get pv`

Comment: Are you using your own mysql image?

Comment: Sometimes you just change path rather than overcome the obstacle.

Comment: I was using the latest official mysql image, but then I went back to the MariaDB. Anyway if can backup the volume, deleting and restarting from scratch is the quickest solution.

Comment: For me apparently the "Initializing database" stage was silently timing out due to a slow disk

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this issue with Kubernetes and MySQL 5.7 as well.

Adding the suggestion from [yosifki](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186#issuecomment-229480846) to my container's definition got things working.

> A new ext4 disk partition is not usually empty;
> there is a lost+found directory, which mysql is known to choke on. You
> could try adding --ignore-db-dir=lost+found to the CMD to know for
> sure (from [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ignore-db-dir))

Here's an extract of my working YAML definition:

```
name: mysql-master
image: mysql:5.7
args:
  - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.

Using mysql:5.6 fixed it.

For more information refer to:

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/69

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this issue. Work around is to delete the pv and pvc and recreate them.

Comment: i've deleted minikube. for nothing

Answer (score 0):

The `do-block-storage` StorageClass you were using might have been formatted with the ext2/3/4 file system, which usually creates a `lost+found` directory at the root.

In addition to using the `--ignore-db-dir=lost+found` option as [suggested by Thiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66027830/2135179), you can also [add `subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath) to your entry in the `volumeMounts` like this:

```yaml
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: test-mysql-volume
              mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
              subPath: mysql
...
```

If you add another container to the pod and mount the volume normally (without using `subPath`), you will see something like this:

```
root@test-mysql-4355v8b79q-cb97l:/# ls -la /data/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root  4096 Jun 28 02:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    29 Jun 28 02:25 ..
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Jun 28 02:23 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x. 5  999 root  4096 Jun 28 02:25 mysql
```

I personally like this method because it should also work with images that require an empty directory but don't have any option to ignore the `lost+found` directory.